# Joya Seed: How to plant?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

Not giving me the option to plant them anywhere but I have three of them? I have tried potted plant, and farm plot.

Comment: Joyas are decorative plants supposed to be planted in a pot. What goes wrong, maybe something blocks the tile or a seed is inaccessible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joya seeds are decorative plants and as such can only be planted in the [Flower Pot](https://oni-db.com/details/flowervase), [Wall Pot](https://oni-db.com/details/flowervasewall), [Hanging Pot](https://oni-db.com/details/flowervasehanging), or [Aero Pot](https://oni-db.com/details/flowervasehangingfancy).

If you select one of these 4 objects and the Joya plant is greyed out, it means that the seeds are inaccessible.